# Spring: Override properties in child context in runtime

Tags: spring, properties, runtime, overriding, applicationcontext

In parent context I have the properties declaration as follows:

```
<bean id="my.properties"
        class="com.rcslabs.webcall.server.property.PropertyPaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" value="classpath:/my.properties"/>
</bean>
```

After, in runtime, I need to create a child context, and override those properties with runtime data. What is the best way to do that?

**ADDITION:**

To be more exact, I'm creating a child context by hand in runtime like this:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext childAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(parentApplicationContext);
```

So, can I declare a bean in the childAppContext, like it is normally done with BeanDefinitionRegistry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a subclass of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, why don't you override `resolveProperty` with logic checking for runtime values and falling back to the defaults otherwise? You may have to create a dedicated subclass for the child context and inject runtime values source in it.

What you could also do is putting your runtime values in System properties and using override mode for `systemPropertiesMode`. This is a simple but not so clean solution, some variation of my first approach would be better. If you create mutliple client contexts this will work as long as you don't spawn them in parallel.

update: I would begin with something like:

```
final Map<String,String> myRuntimeValues;

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext childAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(parentApplicationContext) {
  protected void prepareBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    super.prepareBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.registerSingleton("myRuntimeValues", myRuntimeValues);
  }
};
```

and inject "myRuntimeValues" into PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean defined in client context file. Some more digging could result in a better solution, it's not a typical use case, I am sure you will get farther.

Comment: Yes, I actually use a subclass of the default PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but how do I **pass** the runtime values there? Also, it would be interesting to know, how to inject something into a child context (and use it after).
System properties won't work, because in fact I'll have N child contexts.

Comment: Ok, it looks really good! Possibly, childAppContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(...) will also work (just couldn't find the right method). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @weekens actually "myRuntimeValues" should be available in context before the wiring begins, that's why i did it this way. With your approach it will be too late I'm afraid.

Comment: @mrembisz, how do you inject a Map (`myRuntimeValues`) into a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`?

Comment: @HenryVIII weekens is using his own subclass of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and can have a field there to inject map using standard spring mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on mrembisz's answer, here is the the complete example to dynamically injecting properties into spring context without hardcoding any bean inside child xml and then passing the bean reference from parent context. The below solution does not need a parent context to be defined for this purpose.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    AbstractApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "classpath:spring-beans.xml" }) {
        protected void prepareBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
            super.prepareBeanFactory(beanFactory);
            ArrayList<Properties> prList = new ArrayList<Properties>();
            Properties pr = new Properties();
            pr.setProperty("name", "MyName");
            prList.add(pr);
            Properties prArray[] = new Properties[prList.size()];
            PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pConfig = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            pConfig.setPropertiesArray(prList.toArray(prArray));
            beanFactory.registerSingleton("pConfig", pConfig);
        }
    };
    appContext.refresh();
    System.out.println(appContext.getBean("name"));
}
```